# JQuery datePicker: start/end date should be within one year

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

So if my start date is : `04/22/2010` then my end date selection can be up to `04/22/2011` and after `04/22/2011` are dates all disabled.

Here is what I have for both selection start and end date:

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
  $('#endDate').datepicker({ showOn: 'button', 
      buttonImage: '../images/Calendar.png', 
      buttonImageOnly: true, onSelect: function () { }, 
      onClose: function () { $(this).focus(); } 
    }); 

  $('#startDate').datepicker({ showOn: 'button', 
      buttonImage: '../images/Calendar.png', 
      buttonImageOnly: true, onSelect: 
        function (dateText, inst) { 
          $('#endDate').datepicker("option", 'minDate', new Date(dateText)); 
        } 
      , 
      onClose: function () { $(this).focus(); } 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `maxDate` option at the same time, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
  $('#endDate').datepicker({ showOn: 'button', 
      buttonImage: '../images/Calendar.png', 
      buttonImageOnly: true, onSelect: function () { }, 
      onClose: function () { $(this).focus(); } 
  }); 

  $('#startDate').datepicker({ showOn: 'button', 
      buttonImage: '../images/Calendar.png', 
      buttonImageOnly: true, 
      onSelect: function (dateText, inst) { 
          var nyd = new Date(dateText);
          nyd.setFullYear(nyd.getFullYear()+1);
          $('#endDate').datepicker("option", { minDate: new Date(dateText), 
                                               maxDate: nyd });
      }, 
      onClose: function () { $(this).focus(); } 
  }); 
}); ​
```

[You can play with a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/kEsdR/)

This just gets the date, adds a year (don't use `.getYear`/`.setYear`, they're deprecated) and uses that date to set the `maxDate` property on the other date picker.  If you're curious, [there's a helpful maintained list of javascript `Date` methods here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).